# Undefined symbols: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UnifiedPlayer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, linker-errors

I've been looking through countless posts about this error, and none are solving the issue:

```
undef: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UnifiedPlayer
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UnifiedPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EntertainmentAllStateLandingPage.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UnifiedPlayerHeaderView)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The framework and files are added to `Build Phases`, also tried with `Build Active Architecture Only to No` none of these helped.

Is it something related to bootstrap settings in Terminal?

Please help me solve this issue. I'm using Cocoapods as well.

Comment: Ok. What is it UnifiedPlayer? Where did you get that?

Comment: That's a framework which we are using

Comment: Do you embed it with cocoapods?

Comment: No I have linked it with libraries

Comment: This library doesn't have binaries for simulator, try to build for real device.